# React Admin with OpenID Connect

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to implement a simple OpenID Connect react-admin login using gitlab as OAuth2 service provider.

most of the react-admin examples about OpenID is simple username/password login. But OpenID Connect will do several redirects, and what I come with is make python/flask server redirect to `http://example.com/#/login?token=<token>`, and make react-admin to parsed the URL, and set token in localStorage.

basically is somethings like below:

```
(({ theme, location, userLogin } ) => {
  let params = queryString.parse(location.search);
  if (params.token) {
    userLogin({token: params.token});
  }
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
      <Button href={ '/api/gitlab/login' }>
        Login via GitLab
      </Button>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
});
```

Obviously, that is not good enough, I want to have some advice about how can I improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you followed this example https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html, that **does not** cover the OAuth2 password grant.

```js
// in src/authProvider.js
import { AUTH_LOGIN } from 'react-admin';

export default (type, params) => {
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        const { username, password } = params;
        const request = new Request('https://mydomain.example.com/authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        })
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            });
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

The GitLab guys / girls describe what grants they provide.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#resource-owner-password-credentials-flow

Here is the example how you can get an access token using curl:

```sh
echo 'grant_type=password&username=<your_username>&password=<your_password>' > auth.txt
curl --data "@auth.txt" --request POST https://gitlab.com/oauth/token
```

With the access token you can get some information from the user that is also described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#access-gitlab-api-with-access-token

Here is the example how you can get information from GitLab with the access token that you got from the previous call using curl:

```sh
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH-TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user
```

With some small adjustments in the react-admin example you can use the password credentials flow.

## Here you can find the example that works with GitLab:

https://gist.github.com/rilleralle/b28574ec1c4cfe10ec7b05809514344b

```js
import { AUTH_LOGIN } from 'react-admin';

export default (type, params) => {
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        const { username, password } = params;
        const oAuthParams = {
            grant_type: "password",
            username,
            password
        }
        const body = Object.keys(oAuthParams).map((key) => {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(oAuthParams[key]);
          }).join('&');
        const request = new Request('https://gitlab.com/oauth/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
              },
            body
        })
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(( {access_token} ) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', access_token);
            });
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Cheers
Ralf

Comment: Could you include the relevant parts from those links in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here an good example using oauth flow in react-admin auth provider:
https://github.com/marmelab/ra-example-oauth/blob/master/app/src/authProvider.js